# Is there a better way to search a file for a string?

Tags: c++, search

I need to search a (non-text) file for the byte sequence "9µ}Æ" (or "\x39\xb5\x7d\xc6").

After 5 hours of searching online this is the best I could do. It works but I wanted to know if there is a better way:

```
char buffer;

int pos=in.tellg();

// search file for string
while(!in.eof()){
    in.read(&buffer, 1);
    pos=in.tellg();
    if(buffer=='9'){
        in.read(&buffer, 1);
        pos=in.tellg();
        if(buffer=='µ'){
            in.read(&buffer, 1);
            pos=in.tellg();
            if(buffer=='}'){
                in.read(&buffer, 1);
                pos=in.tellg();
                if(buffer=='Æ'){
                    cout << "found";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    in.seekg((streampos) pos);
```

Note:

- I can't use `getline()`. It's not a text file so there are probably not many line breaks.
- Before I tried using a multi-character buffer and then copying the buffer to a C++ string, and then using `string::find()`. This didn't work because there are many `'\0'` characters throughout the file, so the sequence in the buffer would be cut very short when it was copied to the string.

Comment: why aren't you reading in 4 chars at a time instead of 1?

Comment: You could read a big chunk of bytes at once, store them in an array of bytes, and compare them using `memcmp` or `std::search`. Repeat until EOF, if you wish.

Comment: Are you in a system where you can spawn a grep process?

Comment: ..or 32K at a time?  reading 4 characters is not quite as bad as reading one, but it's getting there..

Comment: @jweyrich Note that in that method you'd need to add some extra logic to detect the case where the byte-sequence spans the border between the end of one chunk and the start of the next...

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what bames53 posted; I used a vector as a buffer:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.bin");

ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streamsize f_size = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(f_size);
ifs.read(buffer.data(), f_size);

std::vector<unsigned char> seq = {0x39, 0xb5, 0x7d, 0xc6};

bool found = std::search(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), seq.begin(), seq.end()) != buffer.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind loading the entire file into an in-memory array (or using mmap() to make it look like the file is in memory), you could then search for your character sequence in-memory, which is a bit easier to do:

```
// Works much like strstr(), except it looks for a binary sub-sequence rather than a string sub-sequence
const char * MemMem(const char * lookIn, int numLookInBytes, const char * lookFor, int numLookForBytes)
{
        if (numLookForBytes == 0)              return lookIn;  // hmm, existential questions here
   else if (numLookForBytes == numLookInBytes) return (memcmp(lookIn, lookFor, numLookInBytes) == 0) ? lookIn : NULL;
   else if (numLookForBytes < numLookInBytes)
   {
      const char * startedAt = lookIn;
      int matchCount = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<numLookInBytes; i++)
      {
         if (lookIn[i] == lookFor[matchCount])
         {
            if (matchCount == 0) startedAt = &lookIn[i];
            if (++matchCount == numLookForBytes) return startedAt;
         }
         else matchCount = 0;
      }
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

.... then you can just call the above function on the in-memory data array:

```
char * ret = MemMem(theInMemoryArrayContainingFilesBytes, numBytesInFile, myShortSequence, 4);
if (ret != NULL) printf("Found it at offset %i\n", ret-theInMemoryArrayContainingFilesBytes);
            else printf("It's not there.\n");
```

Comment: If you're going to load the file into memory anyway, why not just use `std::search`?

Answer (score 0):

This program loads the entire file into memory and then uses `std::search` on it.

```
int main() {
    std::string filedata;
    {
        std::ifstream fin("file.dat");
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fin.rdbuf();
        filedata = ss.str();
    }

    std::string key = "\x39\xb5\x7d\xc6";
    auto result = std::search(std::begin(filedata), std::end(filedata),
                              std::begin(key), std::end(key));
    if (std::end(filedata) != result) {
        std::cout << "found\n";
        // result is an iterator pointing at '\x39'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char delims[] = { 0x39, 0xb5, 0x7d, 0xc6 };
char buffer[4];
const size_t delim_size = 4;
const size_t last_index = delim_size - 1;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < last_index; ++i )
{
  if ( ! ( is.get( buffer[i] ) ) )
    return false; // stream to short
}

while ( is.get(buffer[last_index]) )
{
  if ( memcmp( buffer, delims, delim_size ) == 0 )
    break; // you are arrived
  memmove( buffer, buffer + 1, last_index );
}
```

You are looking for 4 bytes:

```
unsigned int delim = 0xc67db539;
unsigned int uibuffer;
char * buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&uibuffer);

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
  if ( ! ( is.get( buffer[i] ) ) )
    return false; // stream to short
}

while ( is.get(buffer[3]) )
{
  if ( uibuffer == delim )
    break; // you are arrived
  uibuffer >>= 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you said you cannot search the entire file because of null terminator characters in the string, here's an alternative for you, which reads the entire file in and uses recursion to find the first occurrence of a string inside of the whole file.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string readFile (char *fileName) {
      ifstream fi (fileName);
      if (!fi)
        cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open file" << endl;
      else {
        string str ((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fi)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        return str;
      }
      return NULL;
    }

    bool findFirstOccurrenceOf_r (string haystack, char *needle, int haystack_pos, int needle_pos, int needle_len) {
      if (needle_pos == needle_len)
        return true;
      if (haystack[haystack_pos] == needle[needle_pos]) 
        return findFirstOccurrenceOf_r (haystack, needle, haystack_pos+1, needle_pos+1, needle_len);
      return false;
    }

    int findFirstOccurrenceOf (string haystack, char *needle, int length) {
      int pos = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length() - length; i++) {
        if (findFirstOccurrenceOf_r (haystack, needle, i, 0, length))
          return i;
      }
      return pos;
    }

    int main () {
      char str_to_find[4] = {0x39, 0xB5, 0x7D, 0xC6};
      string contents = readFile ("input");

      int pos = findFirstOccurrenceOf (contents, str_to_find, 4);

      cout << pos << endl;
    }
```

If the file is not too large, your best solution would be to load the whole file into memory, so you don't need to keep reading from the drive. If the file is too large to load in at once, you would want to load in chunks of the file at a time. But if you do load in chucks, make sure you check to edges of the chunks. It's possible that your chunk happens to split right in the middle of the string you're searching for.